# Do former names of companies go in quotation marks or in italics?

Tags: style, punctuation, naming, chicago-manual-of-style

I understand that current companies, like Google, do not go in italics or quotes. However, I am editing an article with a sentence that says,

"Founded in 1880 as 'The Bucyrus Foundry and Manufacturing Company,'"

The name above is no longer the name of the company, and anywhere I look online or in the Encyclopedia, they just use bold for the names, which I don't think is appropriate for an article where nothing else is in bold.

(if it makes a difference, the style should be Chicago)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *Kalen*! Are you aiming for answers that are about the Chicago style only, or would you accept answers about AP style, too? I am asking as you used the AP-style tag, too. I don't know a whole lot about the different styles, but I've only seen them used quite distinctly as tags on this site. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Former company names and names of no longer existing companies are given in the same way as current names of currently operating companies.

E.g.

> The Cadillac Motor Company, founded by Henry Ford in 1901 as the Henry Ford Company, became a part of General Motors as the Cadillac Motor Car Division in 1909.

Company names are names and follow their style conventions. Think of a person who changed their name when they married – you wouldn't put their maiden name in quotation marks or italics:

> Jacqueline Kennedy was born 1929 als Jacqueline Lee Bouvier.